# parse mode telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am working on telegram bot and I faced this issue.

code:
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "**My Assets:**", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)

error:
AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'ParseMode'

do I need to install something other than:

pyTelegramBotAPI
python-decouple
python-telegram-bot

any help would be appreciated

help on telegram bot

Comment: check that the telegram-bot library is correctly installed.Run this command `pip install --upgrade python-telegram-bot`
`

Comment: I did, and I am still facing the same error -->

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "<b>My Assets:</b>", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'telegram' has no attribute 'ParseMode'